# How to deal with byClassName in Selenium and PHPUnit

Tags: php, class, selenium, phpunit

I have multiple elements with the same class name and no id, I need to get the first element with the class name. so lets say the html looks like this:

```
<table class="default-table">       
  <thead>
    <tr>    
      <th class="cell"><span class="text"> Title1</span></th>    
      <th class="cell"><span class="text"> Title2</span></th>
      <th class="cell"><span class="text"> Title3</span></th>    
      <th class="cell"><span class="text"> Title4</span></th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="tb">
   <tr>      
     <td class="theInput">
     <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text " data-model-key="item1">    
     </td>

     <td class="theInput">
     <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text " data-model-key="item2">  
     </td>

     <td class="theInput">
     <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text " data-model-key="item3">    
     </td>

     <td class="theInput">
     <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text " data-model-key="item4">    
     </td>
   </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to set the value of the first and third input fields with the class "text", I found a solution if I was using java that looks something like this:

```
classElement = driver.findElements(By.className("text")); 
classElement.get(1).value("1234");
classElement.get(3).value("5678");
```

I'm not sure that it would work as I am not familiar with java but it looks logical, any solution like this in PHP? Or is it a better way then calling the class to access the element in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that looks like this:

```
$items = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('table.default-table input.text'));


$items[0]->value('1234');
$items[2]->value('5678');
```